# ExportAsFixedFormat's IgnorePrintAreas parameter seems not to have effect

Tags: delphi, file-conversion, excel-automation

In a Delphi application I am using since years the following code to export xlxs to pdf:

```
function TExportTool.ExportExcelToPDF(aFileName, aNewFileName: String): Boolean;
// reference : http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.oleautomation/200811/081103142.html
// unluckily the link above is dead
{- Sheet is counted from 1 and upwards !! }
Var
  App,oWB,oSheet : OleVariant;
begin
  Result := False;
  App:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Try
    App.Visible:= 0;
    oWb := App.WorkBooks.Open(ExpandUNCFileName(afilename),1);  // Open read only
    Try
     oSheet := oWB.ActiveSheet;
     oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,  //xlTypePDF is constant 0
                            aNewFileName,
                            EmptyParam, 
                            EmptyParam, 
                            EmptyParam, // this should be IgnorePrintAreas
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam
                            );
    Finally
    End;
    Result := True;
  Finally
    App.Quit;
    App:= UnAssigned;
  End;
end;

// IMPROVED WORKING CODE FOLLOWS

function TExportTool.ExportExcelToPDF(aFileName, aNewFileName: String): Boolean;
// reference : http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.oleautomation/200811/081103142.html
{- Sheet is counted from 1 and upwards !! }

procedure RestoreOriginalPrintArea (oSheet: OleVariant);
// Excel loses print area settings in non-English version of application when file is opened using automation:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379893/exportasfixedformats-ignoreprintareas-parameter-seems-not-to-have-effect
var
  i:Integer;
begin
  for  i:= 1 to oSheet.Names.Count do
  begin
   if VarToStr(oSheet.Names.Item(i).Name).EndsWith('!Print_Area') then
   begin
     oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea:='Print_area';
     Break;
   end;
  end;
end;

Var
  App,oWB,oSheet : OleVariant;
  i:Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  App:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Try
    App.Visible:= 0;
    oWb := App.WorkBooks.Open(ExpandUNCFileName(afilename),1);  // Open read only
    Try
     oSheet := oWB.ActiveSheet;
     RestoreOriginalPrintArea(oSheet);  // workaround
     oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,  //xlTypePDF is constant 0
                            aNewFileName,
                            0, // standard quality = 0, Max quality = 1
                            false, //include doc properties
                            false, //ignore print area
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam,
                            EmptyParam
                            );
    Finally
    End;
    Result := True;
  Finally
    oWB.Close(false); // better to close the WorkBook too
    App.Quit;
    App:= UnAssigned;
  End;
end;
```

Now i realized that the pdf created with this code behave like when saving to pdf from Excel using the option "Ignore Print areas" (it is one of the options of the export to pdf from Excel feature).

So I decided to "uncheck" that checkbox also from code and I studied the parameters of `ExportAsFixedFormat` (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat)).

The fifth parameter is `IgnorePrintAreas`, so I was assuming that passing False to it, the print areas would have been ignored.

I tried several common sense solution, including:

- passing only that parameter (passing either True or False )
- passing all the first 5 parameters (just in case they are mandatory at runtime)

but no result: the pdf created by my application still "ignores the print areas".

Does anyone has a suggestion or has experience on this specific subject to give me a pointer to fix this issue?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the useful accepted answer I appended to the code above the solution for reference, notice two things:

1. the RestoreOriginalPrintArea procedure that contains the workaround
2. the call to oWB.Close(false) at the end

Comment: I've seen it before - it probably isn't an issue with export routine. If you check the value of `oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea` you will probably get an empty string instead of whatever is set there. If you assign any valid range address in your code - export should work as expected. I don't know any fix for this issue.

Comment: @BrakNicku thanks for your comment. I tried to set `oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea`in code just before calling `ExportAsFixedFormat`and in fact what happens is that the pdf  is explored using the print area i set, so the print area is not ignored, anyway setting the printarea does not work as you suggested. Somehow my problem is that "IgnorePrintAreas" parameter is "ignored".

Comment: First you say, that if you set `PrintArea` in code then only this part is exported, and then _anyway setting the printarea does not work as you suggested_. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @BrakNicku my goal is to export to pdf by using the `IgnorePrintAreas` setting. Excel manages to print well if that setting is `false`. Anyway I notice that the pdf generated in code behaves like if that parameter is `true`, but I did not mean to set it true, in fact Iwas not passing any value to it. So I tried to force it to be `false` by passing `false` in the call, but this seems ignored.

Comment: But again: it is not a problem of the export routine, but excel when used in automation does not read PrintArea at all, so no matter what you do - print, export, it will always use whole sheet. Do a test: make `App.Visible:=1`, remove `App.Quit` and test your function on a file where the print area is set. Check the file - the print area settings are no longer there.

Comment: I think I've found a workaround. Add a line `oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea:='Print_Area';` in try...except block before export. If it works - I'll post an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @BrakNicku he suggested workaround works! Thanks a lot. Write an answer and I will accept it, what i did was adding `try oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea:='Print_Area';   except     end;` just before calling `oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`. it does not fo in the except part but it works. before I tried to pass a real print area ($A$1:$T$32') but the result was bad.

Comment: OK, but I'll do it tomorrow, it was quite interesting to investigate:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root cause of error:**

Excel loses print area settings in non-English version of application when file is opened using automation.

**Why this is happening:**

When you define print area in a sheet, Excel internally creates a [named range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name). It has two properties defining its name:

1. `Name` this property is always of the form `WorksheetsName!Print_Area` (if the sheet's name contains some special characters it is also enclosed in single quotes).
2. `NameLocal` has similar structure, but the second part is translated into the language of the application.

This is what it looks like when you open the file in Excel and inspect these properties in VBA, but when you open the same file using automation (for example using the code in question), then `NameLocal` is no longer translated. This bug causes the named range to not be recognized correctly as print area. `oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea` returns an empty string.

**Workaround:**

Restore original print area after opening the file using:

`oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea:='Print_Area';`

This line of code will throw an exception when there was no print area defined in sheet, so there are two options:

1. Place the line inside `try`..`except` block.
2. Iterate the `Names` collection and look for a `Name` ending with `!Print_Area`, for example:

```pascal
var i:Integer;
for  i:= 1 to oSheet.Names.Count do
begin
  if  VarToStr(oSheet.Names.Item(i).Name).EndsWith('!Print_Area') then
  begin
    oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea:='Print_area';
    Break;
  end;
end;
```

**Other important change:**

Because the file could have been modified you also need to add:

`oWB.Close(false); //do not save changes`

before closing the application, otherwise each call to this function would result in  another Excel process still running invisible.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer. I will update my question with the working code. Bye!